cypress intercept to catch everything except baseUrl calls
I have a single page application running in http://localhost:3001 and I have set the baseUrl as such.
Now, I would like to intercept all the external calls, so the ones going elsewhere than localhost:3001. How do I write this kind of single intercept in Cypress? Or am I doing this somehow "wrong" way around, design-wise?
I have tried following intercepts, but they all result in intercepting the http://localhost:3001/_nuxt files etc.
    cy.intercept("**!(localhost:3001)*", (req) => {
    cy.intercept("**!(localhost:3001)**", (req) => {
    cy.intercept(/^((?!http:\/\/localhost:3001).+)$/, (req) => {
    cy.intercept({ url: /^((?!.*localhost:3001).+)$/ }, (req) => {

The wacky part is that, the regex /^((?!.*localhost:3001).+)$/ is correct. It does not match the localhost files.
/^((?!.*localhost:3001).+)$/.exec("http://localhost:3001/_nuxt/components/Component.vue") => null

as it should be, and then

/^((?!.*localhost:3001).+)$/.exec("https://www.example.com")
(2) ['https://www.example.com', 'https://www.example.com', index: 0, input: 'https://www.example.com', groups: undefined]

So, is Cypress intercept doing something more than just a plain regex exec or am I missing something obvious out here?

You can use a partial path
cy.intercept({url: /^((?!.*\/_nuxt).+)$/}, (req) => {

or add the above negative lookahead to your existing regex
cy.intercept({url: /^(?!.*localhost:3001.*)(?!.*\/_nuxt).+$/})

As noted by @D.Nykl - it's better to intercept based on path rather than host & port, as these can change depending on where the page is served from.

Explanation
The bug is at this place in the Cypress code _doesRouteMatch.
When you provide a url it also attempts to match against the path portion of the URL the app uses.
Cypress source code abbreviated to show the relevant lines
export function _doesRouteMatch (routeMatcher: RouteMatcherOptions, req: CypressIncomingRequest) {

  const matchable = _getMatchableForRequest(req)
 
  ...

  // for convenience, attempt to match `url` against `path`?    
  const shouldTryMatchingPath = field === 'url'

  ...

  if (matcher.test) {
    if (!matcher.test(value) && 
       (!shouldTryMatchingPath || !matcher.test(matchable.path))) {
                               // ^ failing here
       return false
     }
     continue
   }

The matchable resolved from http://localhost:3001/_nuxt/components/Component.vue in the first line is:
Matchable object (partial) produced by _getMatchableForRequest(req)
matchable: {
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/_nuxt/components/Component.vue',
  path: '/_nuxt/components/Component.vue',
}

So it also tries this match on the path
/^((?!.*localhost:3001).+)$/.test('/_nuxt/components/Component.vue')

but of course that fails, and _doesRouteMatch does not return false as you would expect it to.
By including part of the path in the cy.intercept() regex you can avoid the bug.

Using path without host or port is a better solution, in case the port changes or you want to run against a deployed site. I think that's Cypress intended best practice since most examples show path fragments.

Thank you! Perfect answer. I was looking for the logic in cypress code but didn't find the correct method, in the end. I can now toy with this better. Good points about the path.

If you want to suppress Cypress logs for a particular route, use
cy.intercept({ ... }, { log: false })     // separate intercept


from Disabling logs for a request

cy.intercept({url: '*'}, (req) => {
  if (!req.url.includes('_nuxt/')) {
    Cypress.log({ name: 'not "/_nuxt/"', message: req.url}) // for demo
  }
}).as('not-nuxt')

cy.intercept(/_nuxt/, {log:false}).as('nuxt')

cy.visit('https://hello-world.example.nuxt.space/')
cy.contains('div', 'Hello Nuxt 3!')



There seems to be a bug in the Cypress intercept code wrt negative lookahead, I could not get any variation to work.
You can however "consume" the localhost:3001 calls before your catch-all intercept.
The intercepts are processed in order of last-setup/first-matched, so if I try the following,
cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
  console.log(req.url)
})
cy.intercept(/jsonplaceholder/, req => req.continue())

cy.visit('/')              // baseUrl is "https://example.com"

cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
})

it does not log the call to jsonplaceholder

But if I comment out the second intercept


There may be a better way to handle this, but you could just intercept all calls, and handle the non-localhost calls differently than the localhost calls.
cy.intercept('**/*', (req) => {
  if (req.url.includes('localhost')) {
    req.continue();
  } else {
    // whatever needs to happen to non-localhost calls
  }
});

In the above, we're checking if the request URL contains localhost, and if it does, we send the request on - almost the same as if it were never intercepted to begin with.

Thanks for the suggestion. Although this works, the problem is that Cypress will now log all the intercepts in the run cluttering everything. So, if you find a way to get rid of the logging of the intercept, this could be doable.
